# Como carregar uma página dentro de uma div com Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, route, angular-routes

Fala galera!!!
Estou com uma mega dúvida e não consigo solucionar. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o TCC da minha faculdade em Angular. Possuo um menu e dentro desse menu há opções para navegar pelo site, porém ao invés de mudar de página, gostaria que essa nova página fosse carregada em uma div que está no mesmo conteúdo, vou postar o código.

Aqui está o meu arquivo com nome de index.component.html que possui o menu.

```
<nav class="menu" tabindex="0">
  <div class="smartphone"></div>
  <header class="avatar"></header>

  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/cadTel']">Cadastro Tele</a></li> 
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/config']">Configuracoes</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
 <div class="carregaPaginas">    
    <span>Tem um texto aqui pra teste</span>
 </div>
</main>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço pra ao clicar na Opção de Menu Cadastro Tele carregar o conteúdo dentro da div carregaPaginas.

Tks!!

---

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataFormModule } from './pages/data-form/data-form.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { Error404Component } from './pages/error404/error404.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './pages/index/index.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   LoginComponent,
   Error404Component,
   IndexComponent,
 ],
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
DataFormModule
```

],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
  export class AppModule { }

e o meu app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Eu preciso que inicie no /login que vem do LoginComponent e que ao logar vá para o IndexComponent (/index) e dentro do index eu consiga utilizar a opção de rota que eu perguntei lá em cima pra carregar dentro da div carregaPaginas.

meu arquivo app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataFormComponent } from './pages/data-form/data-form.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './pages/index/index.component';
import { Error404Component } from './pages/error404/error404.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},

{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'dataForm', component: DataFormComponent },    

{ path: '**', component: Error404Component }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso mesmo, esta faltando a directiva router-outlet, 
Uma saída para roteador emitir um evento de ativação sempre que um novo componente estiver sendo instanciado.

routerLinkActive permite você adicionar um seletor css, caso seja ativado.

```
<nav class="menu" tabindex="0">
  <div class="smartphone"></div>
  <header class="avatar"></header>

  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/cadTel"      routerLinkActive="active"   >Cadastro Tele</a></li> 
    <li><a  routerLink="/config"   routerLinkActive="active"      >Configuracoes</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
 <div class="carregaPaginas">    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Eu teria que colocar o meu principal como o app-module ? se eu não colocar o router outlet lá ele some tuudo

Comment: O meu <router-outlet> está dentro do arquivo app.module.ts, se eu tirar ele de lá some todo o código da página, eu gostaria que o aplicativo iniciasse no localhost:4200/login e ao logar ir para o index.html onde eu configuraria todas essas rotas, porém se tirar o router outlet de dentro do app module some todo o código

Answer (score 0):

Troque essa div pela tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, é nela que vai ser carregada o seus componentes

No seu módulo, configure as rotas e importe

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'cadTel', component: cadTelComponent },
  { path: 'config', component: configComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

De uma olhada na [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Eu teria que colocar o meu principal como o app-module ? se eu não colocar o router outlet lá ele some tuudo

Comment: O meu <router-outlet> está dentro do arquivo app.module.ts, se eu tirar ele de lá some todo o código da página, eu gostaria que o aplicativo iniciasse no localhost:4200/login e ao logar ir para o index.html onde eu configuraria todas essas rotas, porém se tirar o router outlet de dentro do app module some todo o código

Comment: Poste o código do seu `app-module.ts` por favor

Comment: Fiz um novo post (respondi minha pergunta) pra você pode ver. Da uma olhadinha se possível@@@